# bash error handlng - does file exist?

Tags: bash

I have a script to decrypt an encrypted file - but I only want to do it if the file exists.

```
bash -c "openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey key.pem -in encrypted.dat -out decrypted.txt"
```

Is there an easy way to only do this if the .dat file exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if [ -e encrypted.dat ]; then echo exists; else echo does not exist; fi
```

Comment: what the fi at the end?

Comment: @user3437721: The `fi` marks the end of the `if` statement, like the `then` marks the start of the body of the `if` statement and the `else` marks the end of the body of the `if` and the start of the `else` clause.